# ScheduledExecutorService running in main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have 2 ScheduledExecutorService like this:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService writeToLog = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

writeToLog.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        writeToLog();
                    }
                },
                0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS
        );
```

but after run this executor when I check how many thread is running:

```
 int nbRunning = 0;
        for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
            if (t.getState()==Thread.State.RUNNABLE) nbRunning++;
        }
```

I still have 7 thread, before and after this method this same number of running thread. What is wrong here ? I should have 9 thread

Comment: Ehm... why 9? 
 writeToLog(); may b called quite often but why do you expect it to be running when you call Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()?
i mean if writeToLog(); takes some milliseconds (and also Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet() is executed within 1 ms), then it is random if you find it running. Add after writeToLog a thread sleep and check again, then most propably you ll find 9 threads..

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this the thread calling the writeToLog is not in runnable state. After execution of write log, the scheduled thread will enter in the Timed_WAITING state. But you have put a check on runnable state. That is the reason you are not getting the count increment.